# Problem with application reliant on British Summer Time in Azure

Tags: azure, timezone, dst

Part of an on premise app I am moving to the cloud, displays TV Scheduling information from a json source. The core data uses an offset in seconds from a start date to get it's start times which is all fine as these are all int UTC format.

The problem arises in the movement to the cloud.

The on premise app was situated in the UK so the locale is UntedKingdom and the TV times were correctly output using

```
return programmeStart.AddHours(programmeStart.IsDaylightSavingTime() ? 1 : 0);
```

However, having now moved to the cloud, the functionality for IsDaylightSavingTime, no longer returns true due to data centers being BST Agnostic.

Been racking my brains for a way to try and sort this.

Is there a quick and easy way to set what locale your hosted service runs under in Azure, or is the best solution to create an extension method that reads the boundries of when BST runs from and to, and then return true or false from there for example

```
public static class DateTimeExtension
{
  public static bool IsMyDaylightSavingTime(this DateTime timeToTest)
  {
    if(timeToTest >= GetConfig("bstStart") && timeToTest <= GetConfig("bstFinish"))
    {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```

And the maintaing the config values of bst changing as they move?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't change the timezone of the Azure servers - there's lots going on that assumes UTC is the current setting.

You should be able to get hold of the UK timezoneinfo by string, e.g.:

```
TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time");
```

After you've done that, then you can use the framework method `TimeZoneInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460642.aspx

```
tzi.IsDaylightSavingTime(DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: Cheers Stuart
Have gone for
`programmeStart.AddHours(TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time").IsDaylightSavingTime(programmeStart) ? 1 : 0);`

Comment: Why would you code a 1 or 0 when you have the offset?  programmeStart.AddHours(TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time").GetUtcOffset(DateTime.UtcNow)) makes so much more sense.  Not only is it clear what you are adding, but it is future proof should the offset change at some point.  BTW, taking away points for an answer is not very nice when I pointed you to it already and you go and accept the same answer from someone else.

Comment: All our problems are nothing compared to what Samoa programmers will have to think about - http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/australiaandthepacific/samoa/8503614/Samoa-leaps-dateline-how-time-zones-work.html :) I have +1'd the other answer to try to help appease the situation. In an ideal solution, I think I'd use a mix of the two answers - I'd use FindSystemTimeZoneById from this answer and GetOffset from dunnry's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you simply return UTC and let the client translate that per their locale?

Edit:  Here is code

```
var offset = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()
.Where(z => z.Id == "GMT Standard Time")
.Single()
.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.UtcNow)
```

Comment: The TV listings need to show the UK time for the program starts, so client time translation isn't really an option.

Comment: Alright, so I suppose you could use the TimeZoneInfo class and ask for the specific timezone you are looking for in order to do this then.  See this method:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.getsystemtimezones.aspx